# Out string parameter in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this method:

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(ref DbCommand command, out string ErrorMessage)
{
    ErrorMessage = String.Empty;
    DbTransaction tran = null;
    DbConnection conn = null;
    int result = 0;
```

This method is used when accessed on another page. I pass a command in the form of SQLcommand to which I pass a query, but I don't get what this `out string` is for. This is someone else's code, but I want to use it for abstraction purposes of insertion queries. How should I get the errormessage parameter as it says it's an out string.

I want to do like this on one of my pages:

```
string Email = "example@example.com";
string Password = "Hello";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into J_example_Tbl(J_example_Email,J_example_Password) VALUES('"+Email+"','"+Password+"')");

PrimaryDBClass.ExecuteNonQuery(command, "Should I do like this");
```

Comment: Please *don't* use string concatenation to pass parameters into SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead. (And having an `out` parameter for an error message is a bad idea - use exceptions instead. And your command almost certainly shouldn't be passed by reference. Basically this whole code looks like it should be revisited.)

Comment: as @JonSkeet, says read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: _How should get the errormessage parameter as it says its an out string,_ After you call the method, there's a string reference in the `out` variable (possibly a `null` reference). So call it like this: `DbCommand command = ...; string errorMessage; int count = ExecuteNonQuery(ref command, out errorMessage); /* here check if 'errorMessage' is null, or a message text */`

Comment: See also MSDN for [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) parameter modifiers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding

> but I don't get what this out string is for

Out is stands for pointing to a variable. The `out` keyword describes parameters whose actual variable locations are copied onto the stack of the called method, where those same locations can be rewritten. This means that the calling method will access to the changed parameter.

**For example:** If you declare a variable named `test` in `class1` and want to change the value from another class, `class2`, and still want to get the changed value from `class1` you have to send the test variable with the `out` keyword from `class1` to `class2`.

Which means in your method:

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(ref DbCommand command, out string ErrorMessage)
```

If any change occurred in variable ErrorMessage it will point to the actual variable where from it comes. So you will get the changed value from outside of the method ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Oh wao! Nice explanation Rezoan, Now i got it! Thanks alot

Comment: You welcome. and don't forget to mark it as answer if it's the answer you are expecting. so the others who have faced the same problem can get the right answer@ Majid Khan Mohmand

Comment: Yep i did it. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

The `out` parameter can be used like this:

```
string Email = "example@example.com";
string Password = "Hello";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into J_example_Tbl(J_example_Email,J_example_Password) VALUES('"+Email+"','"+Password+"')");
string error;
PrimaryDBClass.ExecuteNonQuery(command, out error);

if(error != null)
 ....
```

You should probably check for the result in some other way (like checking the return value or something). Look at Jon Skeet's suggestions as well.

Comment: Thanks Alot for your time guys, i really appreciate it! I will surely walk around your suggestions and tips.